# Java Android Bound mismatch

Tags: java, android

I am still relatively new to Java, and am trying to work with the code at the address. http://proyectouvipool.googlecode.com/svn-history/r87/trunk/Android/PFC/src/pablo/developer/BalloonItemizedOverlay.java

Unfortunately, I get the following error message

**Bound mismatch: The type Item is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type BalloonOverlayView**

at code

```
protected BalloonOverlayView<Item> createBalloonOverlayView() {
      return new BalloonOverlayView<Item>(getMapView().getContext(), getBalloonBottomOffset());
     }
```

Would appreciate some help on what to do to fix this?

Comment: Sound like you have imported the wrong `Item` class. Please post your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomBalloonItemizedOverlay extends
            BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

        private ArrayList<OverlayItem> m_overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        private Context c;

        public MyFavoritePlacesItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker,
                MapView mapView) {
            super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView);
            c = mapView.getContext();
        }

        public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
            m_overlays.add(overlay);
            populate();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
            if (!shadow) {
                super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
            }
        }

        public void removeOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
            m_overlays.remove(overlay);
            populate();
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return m_overlays.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return m_overlays.size();
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
            // Your code... 
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Below is how to use that...

initGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                        (int) (longitude * 1E6));

```
            mapOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
drawableImage = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.any_icon);

CustomBalloonItemizedOverlay customItemizedOverlayObject = new public class CustomBalloonItemizedOverlay(
                    drawableImage, myMapView);
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(initGeoPoint, name,
                    address);

            customItemizedOverlayObject.addOverlay(overlayItem);
            mapOverlays.add(customItemizedOverlayObject);

        }
```